# Overwrite type definitions for (alias) const in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extend the Props interface of the default export of a react native library but I'm having a hard time with it.

`tailwind-provider.d.ts`

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { ColorSchemeName } from 'react-native';
import { Utilities } from './types';
interface Props {
    utilities: Utilities;
    colorScheme?: ColorSchemeName;
}
declare const TailwindProvider: React.FC<Props>;
export default TailwindProvider;
```

My goal is to add the children property and this was my attempt

`App.tsx`

```js
import { TailwindProvider, Utilities } from 'tailwind-rn'
import utilities from './tailwind.json'
import { ColorSchemeName } from 'react-native'

import * as React from 'react';

interface Props {
  utilities: Utilities;
  colorScheme?: ColorSchemeName;
  children?: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[]
}

declare type TailwindProvider = React.FC<Props>
```

I have also tried

```js
import { TailwindProvider as TailwindProvider, Utilities } from 'tailwind-rn'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the imported module by assigning it to a new constant and then asserting the new modified type

```ts
import { TailwindProvider, Utilities } from 'tailwind-rn'

interface TWProps {
  utilities: Utilities;
  colorScheme?: ColorSchemeName;
  children?: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[]
}

const TailwindProviderContext = TailwindProvider as unknown as React.FC<TWProps>

<TailwindProviderContext utilities={utilities}>
</TailwindProviderContext>
```